# Why does Task.Run(() => something) that calls a sync method that awaits deadlock?

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library, deadlock

I'm trying to figure out where a deadlock is happening in a TPL program that I'm converting from using WebRequest/WebResponse to HttpClient.

I've got a loop that creates 100 tasks and puts them in an array:

```
var putTasks = new Task[100];
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    putTasks[i] = Task.Run(() => client.Put("something"));
}
Task.WaitAll(putTasks);
```

The code is hanging on Task.WaitAll and looking at the server side shows that the first request completes, but the rest don't.

The weird part about this (and yes, it should be async all the way through, but it's not right now, and I'm trying to understand why it's deadlocking before I make it entirely async) is that client.Put is a synchronous method that looks like this:

`string Put(string thing) { return PutAsync(string thing).GetAwaiter().GetResult(); }`

and PutAsync looks like:

```
async Task<string> PutAsync(string thing)
{
    //httpClient built up here
    HttpContent content = new StringContent(thing);

    var response = await httpClient.PutAsync("http://myuri", content);
    var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
    // Do some stuff
}
```

The part it's hanging on inside PutAsync is the `response = await httpClient.PutAsync`. I've seen a bunch of answers around deadlocking in a UI thread but none of the fixes (e.g. changing the captured context) help.

Ideally I'd just make it all async all the way down and await everything but as I said, I'm trying to figure out why the deadlock is happening and where it's happening before I tear everything apart - the other problem is this is a library used by other people, and the interface is synchronous methods, so I can't just change it to async and update a bunch of hidden code.

Comment: PutAsync will be creating it's own Task. So the array of Tasks you declare is not needed. Remove the `Task.Run(()` put your code in a method and  mark it `async` and await the `client.Put` call

Comment: I'm "masking" the task `PutAsync` creates - basically, I'm converting a sync library to use async behind the scenes code, so the `Put` method does not return a `Task`, it just returns a `string`. Actually, I might be completely wrong here - if I let this sit long enough, it DOES work so I wonder if it's blocking on the connection pool of the shared HttpClient or something.

Comment: @HighlyUnavailable If it does work then it's not a deadlock. It's probably throttling because there's a limit to how many requests you can send to the same domain at a time.

Comment: It's to a service running on localhost. There is no throttling. Whatever, I think this was a false "deadlock" - I'll close it out.

Comment: I also believe Task.Run will queue the work onto the Thread pool, of which there is a limited number of threads. So I suspect some of the tasks will delay until others are complete. I may be wrong though

Comment: @William You're right there, but they're not queueing - they all just pause for about a minute, then complete simultaneously. From the server side, there is no activity until they all suddenly send the requests. The requests aren't even getting sent during the "dead" period.

Comment: [This is simple not the way await/async code should be run](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

Comment: @ErikPhilips Then please post an answer enlightening me on how I should take an API that provides synchronous methods (e.g. a `client.Put(string thing)` method and hook it up to an async method behind the scenes. If I change the client.Put() method to use an awaiter internally, and await on the result, it has the same problem. Since this is a public interface, I can't change Put() itself to return a Task, but I can do whatever I want inside Put().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was all the running tasks to call the sync API filled up the threadpool so that the async calls that the HttpClient had to do had no threads to run on.

Answer (score 3):

> Then please post an answer enlightening me on how I should take an API that provides synchronous methods (e.g. a client.Put(string thing) method and hook it up to an async method behind the scenes.

[**You don't**.  Doing so doesn't provide any benefit.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx)  Only the person who provided the library should be wrapping calls they know for fact [call some type of Completion Port](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html).  Creating a separate thread (`Task.Run()`) to wait for a resource is simply wasting a resource (there are exceptions).

> I can't just change it to async and update a bunch of hidden code.

And you shouldn't.

> The part it's hanging on inside PutAsync is the `response = await httpClient.PutAsync`

99% of deadlocks are caused because the **caller** to `MethodAsync()` is done incorrectly, without that specific code, knowing why is unanswerable.

**This is only useful if you know you are using completion ports**

I can't demonstrate a `PutAsync` because the requirements to create a true async method aren't available on `HttpClient`.  Instead I'll create on for [SqlCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand(v=vs.110).aspx) for `ExecuteNonQuery()`:

```
public static Task<int> ExecuteNonQueryAsync(this SqlCommand sqlCommand)
{
  var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();

  sqlCommand.BeginExecutedNonQuery(result =>
  {
    tcs.SetResult(sqlCommand.EndExecutedNonQuery());
  });

  return await tcs.Task;
}
```

Granted this is very poorly coded, no try/catch etc, but it doesn't use `Task.Run()` to start another thread that does nothing.

Now if you want to properly do Parallel Task calling with async tasks then something like this is more appropriate (and doesn't waste threads):

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<HttpResponseMessage>> GoCrazy()
{
  var putTasks = new List<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>();

  for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
  {
    var task = client.PutAsync("something");
    putTasks.Add(task);
  }

  // WhenAll not WaitAll
  var result = await Task.WhenAll(putTasks);

  return result;
}
```

Comment: I'd highly recommend watching [Async Best Practicies for C# and Visual Basic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f8v5EQRfQaA) and read [Stephen Cleary's blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/) there is a crazy amount of good information there.

Comment: The only reason I'm doing this is I want this library to compile under the new version of .NET, and as of DNXCore50, Microsoft has completely removed the synchronous HTTP client (WebRequest/WebResponse) and replaced it with a requirement to use HttpClient. Your example of a SQL client does not help, since as you say, "The requirements to create a true async method aren't available on HttpClient". Anyway, I already figured out the problem, and it was that the tasks to try to multithread the puts were blocking the http call tasks.

Comment: Is there any benefit to using async/await in the GoCrazy method? Why not remove the async keyword and just `return Task.WhenAll(putTasks);`? Also, the GoCrazy method must return a task; the current implementation would not compile.

Comment: @Palec You can't await a non-async method so the caller couldn't await it.  If that was the case then there would be no purpose to using await/async and the only other answers is to waste threads with `Task.Run`.

Comment: You can await [any method returning an awaitable](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/task-asynchronous-programming-model#BKMK_ReturnTypesandParameters), which is any type that implements GetAwaiter method. The method itself may or may not be implemented using async-await. It may just directly create a task or return the task returned by another method it calls. Async-await is just syntactic sugar creating a state machine, akin to the state machine created by [yield](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield).

Comment: `async Task<int> Foo() => await Task.FromResult(42);` is a less performant equivalent of `Task<int> Foo() => Task.FromResult(42);`. Same as `IEnumerable<int> Bar { foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(1, 5)) yield return i; }` is a less performant equivalent of `IEnumerable<int> Bar => Enumerable.Range(1, 5);`.

Comment: None of your examples should use Tasks because they don't use either; A completion Port or B high cpu methods that need to be parallelized.